# I want to check if a key exists in a dictionary, what is the better between using a get method on dictionary and using `in`?

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization

I have a dictionary in python of, say, names of students and their age.

```
students = {"Mark": 25, "Sundar": 30, "Satya": 40}
```

I want to check if a student exists in the dictionary. Notice I don't need the value corresponding to the key, I just need to know if a key exists in the given dictionary.

I have two options, first is to

```
students.get(key, False)
```

Second is to do

```
key in students
```

Which one is better if there is any difference. Particularly trying to understand how these two work under the hood.

Comment: I don't think that performance matters in your case. My advice is to chose the most expressive solution, which is `key in students` IMO. `students.get(key, False)` doesn't feel natural to me, also because its type is `int | bool` (with `int` having _age_ semantics).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about under the hood, but

```
key in students
```

is definitely preferable to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 4):

I write benchmark like below for `1_000_000` students but consider multi assumption:

1. As said in the comments and other answer: It's better to use an expressive and readable solution (Use `in` in this problem and the benchmark say `in` is better.)
2. Suppose all value of your `dict` have `value > 0` for checking condition and return True or False with `.get()`.

**Benchmark on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)**

```
import random, string
students = {}

# Creating random `student_name as key` and random `number as value` 
for _ in  range(1_000_000):
    key = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=10))
    students[key] = random.choice(range(1,1000))

def dct_get_app(dct, key):
    return dct.get(key, False) > 0

def dct_in_app(dct, key):
    return key in dct


# select  one key from dictionary that exist
%timeit dct_get_app(students, 'VHKVTRNUHI')
# 10000000 loops, best of 5: 169 ns per loop

%timeit dct_in_app(students, 'VHKVTRNUHI')
# 10000000 loops, best of 5: 128 ns per loop

# select one key from dictionary that not exist
%timeit dct_get_app(students, 'A')
# 10000000 loops, best of 5: 162 ns per loop

%timeit dct_in_app(students, 'A')
# 10000000 loops, best of 5: 121 ns per loop
```